# Is there a built-in way to register only for specific topics?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, event-bus

I want to use signalR to broadcast events from my server to the client proxies.
The server uses the multi tenancy architecture and I want to seperate each tenant in the signalR-Hub by the signalR groups.

Furthermore I want to broadcast my "framework events" thru signalR. The client should register himself for the events he need.
Can this problem be covered by "signalR-Topics" or must the client register only the events he wants, like:

```
myHub.On<string>("addMessage", param => {
                Console.WriteLine(param);
            });
```

This sample has the restriction, that all events/methods must be defined on the server, and if the framework gets a new event, I also habe to add a new signalR method/event.

The other problem is: That if the client wants to unsuscribe from "addMessage"?
Is it possible to remove the registration "myHub.On("addMessage"..." while runtime?

An other idea:
That if I only publish "one" generic event-method, with an additional string parameter "topic". The clients can register on startup for specific "topics" and on the server-side it can be determined which clients get the event.
I would store the client/topic mapping in a dictionary.

```
var topciMapping = Dictionary<string, List<string>>;
//the key is the topic name, and the list contains the signalR connectionIds
```

The next question will be: Can I send events to a custom list of connectionIds?

This should do the trick, right?

```
var connectionIds = new List<string>();
Clients.Clients(connectionIds)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list of all `connectionIDs` you want to send the message to, you ca basically just do this:

```
    foreach(var connectionId in ConnectionList) 
       Clients.Client(connectionId).sendMessage(message);
```

Hope this helps.

Best of luck!

Comment: Have I to use foreach? Will "Clients.Clients(connectionIds)" do the same? The variable 'connectionIds' is the list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

The "other idea" makes absolutely sense. Note that there already is a possibility to address groups by name, which could very well suit your topics. That way you already have the users grouped that you can then easily address:

```
Clients.Group(groupName).addChatMessage(name, message);
Clients.OthersInGroup(groupName).addChatMessage(name, message);
```

Reference: [Working with groups in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups)

**EDIT**

The generic method is the way to go then. Also, the topic `Dictionary` makes sense based on what you said in the comment that you're already using `groups`. Also the addressing via `Clients.Clients(connectionIds)` should work.

So in general if you're asking if this is a decent approach, then I'd say yes. I couldn't find anything about "SignalR-Topics", wondering if I missed something.

Comment: The "groups" I already use for my "multi-tenant" support. Each tenant is a group. I cant use multiple groups because it would send the message to all groups. It would only work if I can say: "Send it to all users that are in GroupA AND in GroupB".

Comment: Example: Send message to: All users in Group "CustomerA" AND is in the Group "RegisteredForCreationEvents"

Comment: Okay thanks. I saw the signalr topics here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.messaging.topic(v=vs.118).aspx but I think it is not what I need.

Comment: Seems to be unrelated, at least for the Hub context. Did you get any further?

Comment: I got this on msdnhttp://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections it is the same I did. I think I will stick to the inmemory Client Mapping to a topic list.